# Auto structure divs box on free space

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: Example]

The main idea is to get width and height from divs (boxes) from Backend and then I want a function or something in react that will structure page like this.

I found this name is Mansory, I want to do a it like it.

Sometimes the big box (Mentions) can stay on top right.
I want the small boxes to occupy empty space. I was thinking about using tables to structure it but I can't figure out how to make a function to do this automatically and dynamically.

So the idea is to never have free space, there always be a box there.

I think you guys got the idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS flexbox to do so.
setting `flex-wrap: wrap` in the container and using `flex-grow: #desiredSize` for items will probably do.

here is a great guide by css-tricks:
[A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: I want to do something like a Mansory you know? I think flex its not the best way I guess..

Comment: Do you mean the Mansory car tuning brand?!
I don't know what exactly you have in mind but if you have a guess for the solution and don't know how to implement it, I might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure receiving width and height dimensions from the backend is a good idea, this will not result in a responsive website. For your use case, CSS may be the best solution.
You can use either Flexbox or CSS Grid. In my opinion, a screen like this can work really well with CSS Grid and template-areas. Take a look at [this.](https://css-tricks.com/simple-named-grid-areas/)

Comment: I want to do something like a Mansory you know? I think flex its not the best way I guess..